# Vertex AI - Sample Notebook Authentication

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, jupyter-notebook, google-cloud-vertex-ai

Vertex AI created the below sample notebook. When I run it I get a unauthorized error. I don't see any exmaples on what the authentication setup would be like. Would it be a API key, username/password, etc? What would the code consist of?

```
!pip install --upgrade google-cloud-aiplatform

import base64
import vertexai
from vertexai.preview.generative_models import GenerativeModel

def generate():
  model = GenerativeModel("gemini-pro-vision")
  responses = model.generate_content(
    ["""What is the date today?"""],
    
    generation_config={
        "max_output_tokens": 2048,
        "temperature": 0.4,
        "top_p": 1,
        "top_k": 32
    },
    )
  
  print(responses)

generate()
```

Comment: where are you running the code, locally on any notebook or in console?

Comment: always put FULL error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not in comments) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information in the full error/traceback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to do it locally is to add:

```
import os
os.environ["GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS"]="/key.json"
```

Before `generate()`

Get your project key in IAM / Service Accounts / Key -> Add Key -> Download as json

Comment: I was unsure of where to get the "key.json" file so that part was quite helpful.

Answer (score 1):

A few things you can try :

First, You must enable the Vertex AI API in Google Cloud.

Here is a doc on that: https://cloud.google.com/vertex-ai/docs/start/cloud-environment#enable_vertexai_apis

Second, you must make sure that you have the IAM Permissions to use Vertex API in the manner in which you want. You have to make sure that your GCP account is has the correct permissions attached to it. There are several ways to do this.

The requried roles for Vertex AI for this are as follows: (roles/aiplatform.user)
and for a bit more access use (roles/aiplatform.admin).

For more background on that, go here: https://cloud.google.com/vertex-ai/docs/general/access-control

If you want to use Vetex Notebooks you will also need (roles/notebooks.admin) and (roles/iam.serviceAccountUser.

Here is a doc on how to handle permssions more generally in Google Cloud if you need it: https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/granting-changing-revoking-access